# каким свойством можно строить grid с права на лево?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, grid

Прикреплю картинку необходимого результата:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2vw;
  }
#grid > div {
  font-size: 5vw;
  padding: .5em;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кхм.. Думаю проще на флексах.

Answer (score 2):

Подход как у Get-Web, но всего два правила. Работает с любым количеством элементов:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2vw;
}

.grid>div {
  font-size: 5vw;
  padding: .5em;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid>div:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+1) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.grid>div:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(3n+1) {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, ваш вариант явно красивее, на скорую руку накидал идею, поспешил..

Comment: @Get-Web Вы просто задумались о первых элементах, а я с последних начал, ведь когда их всего 1-2 - они же и есть последние. В любом случае, мы с вами выбрали подход, который кажется единственно возможным, а спешить не стоит ))